# Error : NS_ERROR_FAILURE in firefox while use getBBox()

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to use method **getBBox()** for getting width and height of element created in SVG

here I provide my code which gives result in chrome but not firefox

Please help me how to solve it..

```js
try {
  console.log(document.getElementById("rect1").getBBox());
  console.log(document.getElementById("rect2").getBBox());
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

#rect2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200" style="border:1px dashed blue">
    <rect id="rect1" width="50" height="50" fill="steelblue"></rect>
    <rect id="rect2" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" x="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 11):

It is because by using `display: none` the SVG is not rendered. You should use in your CSS `visibility: hidden` or check the rect style in JS before invoke `getBBox()`.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("rect1").getBBox());
console.log(document.getElementById("rect2").getBBox());
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

#rect2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200" style="border:1px dashed blue">
    <rect id="rect1" width="50" height="50" fill="steelblue"></rect>
    <rect id="rect2" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" x="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and there was nothing hidden, turns out that FF throw exception from getBBox if width and height is 0. If you have generic code and you by chance get element that don't have width or height you need to filter those elements out in FF.

Comment: How did you figure out that `getBBox` fails for height and width = 0? Do you use CSS properties or the result of `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: @BairDev I think I was using chrome dev tools, my code was using jQuery, I don't remember exactly how I've found this. I wanted to report this issue to Firefox but was not able to reproduce it. This is the PR to GGTips project that I've found this https://github.com/Roche/ggtips/pull/38 I was not investigating further why I was not able to reproduce it. You can see issue https://github.com/Roche/ggtips/issues/36 for more details.

Comment: @BairDev maybe I should search little bit more and report the issue to Firefox maybe the issue is in different function, but the fix will be the same filter out items with 0 width and height.

Comment: There is already a nice ticket for FF with a similar point: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984752

Comment: @BairDev not sure if it's related, there were few bugs reported with similar error messages none of them seems related. And in my code there are also clip-masks I'm also not sure if that's related to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html template and css, javascript then ,
remove class with property display:none above the map class and add some new class.

Next after loading or executing getbox function attach that removed class(having property display: none) through javascript.

it is simple and quick solution.