# Firefox SVG: getBBox method throws when called on element inside <mask>

Tags: firefox, svg

I saw many questions about NS_ERROR_FAILURE when calling `getBBox` in Firefox, and as I understand, element must be visible before calling this:

[Error : NS_ERROR_FAILURE in firefox while use getBBox()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184101/error-ns-error-failure-in-firefox-while-use-getbbox)

But in my case, element is part of `<mask>`, and it seems that Firefox does not recognize it as visible element at all.

Markup is following:

```
<svg>
  <mask id="mask">
    <text
       dominantBaseline="central"
       textAnchor="middle"
       x="50%" y="50%"
       fill="white"
    >
      ...
    </text>
  </mask>
  <image mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="..." width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

and I'm using `getBBox` on `<text>` to use it's dimensions as `viewBox` params (i.e., to stretch text at all available space inside svg).

With this, inspector shows that `<text>` has dimensions `0x0`, like if it was invisible or not present in DOM.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Create a copy of the text outside the mask and measure that.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, it's helpful. 
I just added same text node besides image, and it works, and even does not cause any undesired visual effects.